# Sql Server conversion problem? From String to DateTime? The problem is that i don't have String fields

Tags: sql-server, date

I would like to Select a specific date but mySql says that there is a conversion problem..

Here is my structure

```
Table AssAttestati

ID int Allow Nulls (No),
matricola varchar(MAX) Allow Nulls (YES),
attestato int Allow Nulls (YES),
dataS date Allow Nulls (YES),
scadenza date Allow Nulls (YES),
PDF varchar(250) Allow Nulls (YES),
validita int Allow Nulls (YES).
```

```
Table Attestati

ID int Allow Nulls (No),
nome varchar(250) Allow Nulls (YES),
descrizione varcha(250) Allow Nulls (YES),
preavvisoScadenza int Allow Nulls (YES),
ente varchar(MAX) Allow Nulls (YES),
validita int Allow Nulls (YES)
```

```
Table Dipendenti

ID int Allow Nulls (No),
nome varchar(50) Allow Nulls (YES),
cognome varchar(50) Allow Nulls (YES)
matricola varchar(MAX) Allow Nulls (Yes)
```

```
Sql Instruction
SELECT Dipendenti.cognome,
       Dipendenti.nome,
       AssAttestati.dataS,
       AssAttestati.scadenza,
       Dipendenti.matricola,
       AssAttestati.PDF,
       AssAttestati.ID
FROM OliveroS.dbo.Dipendenti
     INNER JOIN OliveroS.dbo.AssAttestati ON Dipendenti.matricola = AssAttestati.matricola
WHERE AssAttestati.attestato = 11
  AND AssAttestati.scadenza >= '24/06/2018'
UNION
SELECT Dipendenti.cognome,
       Dipendenti.nome,
       Dipendenti.matricola,
       AssAttestati.dataS,
       AssAttestati.scadenza,
       AssAttestati.PDF,
       AssAttestati.ID
FROM OliveroS.dbo.Dipendenti
     INNER JOIN OliveroS.dbo.AssAttestati ON Dipendenti.matricola = AssAttestati.matricola
WHERE AssAttestati.attestato = 11
  AND AssAttestati.scadenza IS NULL
ORDER BY Dipendenti.cognome;
```

It says "Error conversion from String to Date" but I don't have a String Fields they are clearly: scadenza(date) and dataS(date)

Comment: Please post the whole error message

Comment: Don't know how to translate it properly from italian..
Conversion failed while converting a character string to a date or time.

Comment: it is the `3rd` column of your `union` query.  `AssAttestati.dataS` is `date` while `Dipendenti.matricola` is `varchar`

Comment: White space and aliases make for much more readable SQL.

Comment: Your table `Dipendenti` doesn't have a column `matricola`; is that SQL really correct or do we have incomplete definitions? You *should* be getting an invalid column error.

Comment: Sorry i updated correctly...

Comment: `AssAttestati.scadenza >= '24/06/2018'` compares a localized *string* with a `date` column. How that string is translated depends on the server's locale. Don't use that format *at all*. For starters, use parameterized queries with strongly typed `date` parameters. If you can't (why?) use the `YYYYMMDD` format, which is the only unambiguous date format

Comment: Then @Squirrel is right. a `UNION( ALL)` query must return the same data types in both data sets.

Comment: @MiteNikolov Did you try with `AssAttestati.scadenza >= '2018-06-24` instead of `AssAttestati.scadenza >= '24/06/2018'`?

Comment: @Sami yeah i tried all... The standard format ```20182406``` ```2018-06-24``` i also tried with the time ```20182406 00:00:00``` still nothing....

Comment: @Sami even this format *may* be affected by `DATEFORMAT` if the target type is `datetime`.

Comment: @MiteNikolov *what exactly* did you try? Because `YYYYMMDD` works. So does `YYYY-MM-DD` with `date`. Don't make people guess. Post enough code to reproduce the problem - a `CREATE TABLE` statement that contains the fields in question and a query that reproduces the problem

Comment: sorry didn't know that i need to post the query with create table...

Comment: @Squirrel didn't understand well what you mean

Comment: @MiteNikolov the column order in the second query is mixed up

Comment: @all thank you guys your a great community! Now I would like to close the question
and can't find the way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns in the UNION's SELECT statements are mixed up. The first query returns  :

```
Dipendenti.cognome,
Dipendenti.nome,
AssAttestati.dataS,
AssAttestati.scadenza,
....
```

While the second returns :

```
Dipendenti.cognome,
Dipendenti.nome,
Dipendenti.matricola,
AssAttestati.dataS,
...
```

This means it returns a `varchar(max)` field where a `date` was expected. The query engine will try to convert that to a `date` and fail with a conversion error when the first unparsable string is found.

Change the second query's SELECT to match the first query :

```
SELECT Dipendenti.cognome,
       Dipendenti.nome,
       AssAttestati.dataS,
       AssAttestati.scadenza,
       Dipendenti.matricola,
       AssAttestati.PDF,
       AssAttestati.ID
```

In any case using `varchar(max)` just for convenience is a bad idea. Those fields are used to store BLOBs that don't need to be indexed and use different storage. Joining over those fields will lead to full table scans of both tables

Comment: Ok, good job! Now is working like a charm! Thanks for the Tips on the varchar datatype field... I used varchar(MAX) for the name because someone has 4-5 names and I'm afraid that it won't fit